# Where can I find the amended/improvised checklists for Apollo 13 post-accident?

Tags: apollo-program, reference-request, apollo-13

I have been trying to find this online without too much avail. For my own reference and cross checking, I wanted to know where I could find the emergency checklists and the "made up on the spot" CM restart checklist for the Apollo program. Does anyone have these resources bookmarked or know where I can find said resources without contacting NASA?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for bare links to specific external resources, rather than answers that explain things.

Comment: I think reference requests are on-topic here.

Comment: You might be able to find something in the list of documents at the [Apollo 13 Flight Journal](http://history.nasa.gov/ap13fj/documents.htm). Also recordings and transcriptions were kept routinely, so there should be a recording or transcript of the read up. According to [this](http://history.nasa.gov/ap13fj/fplan/a13-flightplan-54-splash.pdf) a first powerup procedure was read up at around 111 hours?

Comment: The [Apollo 13 Technical Air-to-Ground Voice Transcription](http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/mission_trans/apollo13.htm) should be useful. Hat tip to [TildalWave](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/49/tildalwave), link from [this answer to a question of mine](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/2554/415) about the CM AGC shutdown. It won't necessarily give you much in terms of *why* but it should give you all of the *what*.

Comment: Take a look at the Apollo 13 Review Board Report, http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/lunar/apollo_13_review_board.txt